# 2012 R2 RDVH DCOM Error

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds, dcom

I'm trying to install RDVH service from my broker to my hyper-v server.
But it fails and returns: "Cannot get integrity informations", and in the Events Viewer, I can see a DCOM error that tells me it could not connect to the server with a pid and wmsprovhost.exe ...

I can manage this server (RDVH, lets say server B) from my broker (server A). So I'm not sure DCOM is not working, else I would get a ServerManager.exe error, no ?

I enabled DCOM rule in FW but still the same.

Before modifying the registry as mentionned here (http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_28189261.html), do u guys, have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I troubleshoot networks related problems, and port 135 was blocked between servers. Now everything's OK !